# Flutter- compute method

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to execute heavy method by `compute()`.
I tried like so. 
After `loop` executed, `Text` widget update but `result` returns 0 almost right after button was pressed.
Does anyone know what am I missing?

```
 int _counter;

  static int loop(int val) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= val; i++) {
      count += i;
    }
    return count;
  }

  Future<void> _onPressed() async {
    int result = await compute(loop, 1000000000000000000);
    setState(() {
      _counter = result;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

According to https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/compute-constant.html,

> The callback argument must be a top-level function, not a closure or an instance or static method of a class.

Please remove the `static` keyword, it should work fine

Comment: This is probably out of date: **The function used as callback must be one that can be sent to an isolate. Qualifying functions include: top-level functions, static methods, closures that only capture objects that can be sent to an isolate.**

Answer (score 14):

Here is an example of compute:

```
final sum = await compute(computationallyExpensiveTask, 1000000000);
```

And this is the function that is run in the compute isolate:

```
int computationallyExpensiveTask(int value) {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= value; i++) {
    sum += i;
  }
  print('finished');
  return sum;
}
```

#### Notes:

- As mentioned in the accepted answer, the function that you give to `compute` must be a top level function (not inside a class).

#### Code

Here is the full code in context. The circular progress indicator stops spinning because the UI is blocked when you do the `computationallyExpensiveTask` directly.

[image]

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: BodyWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BodyWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('start'),
            onPressed: () async {
              final sum = computationallyExpensiveTask(1000000000);
              //final sum = await compute(computationallyExpensiveTask, 1000000000);
              print(sum);
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


int computationallyExpensiveTask(int value) {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= value; i++) {
    sum += i;
  }
  print('finished');
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: Demo snippet lags for my case [debugMode-chorme on windows10]. Also tied with `await` but  not able to fix UI-blocked.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh, did you comment out the line above the `await` line when you got the blocked with `await`?

Comment: I've tried & didn't see any difference. The ProgressIndicator is freezing for both statement.