# Heavy operation flutter sqlite background

Tags: flutter, dart

I ask you a quwstion because i Need to develop an application with background synchronization. I tried to look around but i didn't find something usefull. My requirement Is to do background fetch of datas from apis and save them to database. One sunchronization can be heavy(12k inserits). It this process block UI?

The user could continue to use app while synchronizing.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For heavy read/write, you can use https://pub.dev/packages/hive instead of sqlite 
`Hive` have better performance than `sqlite`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a dedicated isolate to perform heavy calculations, for that you can use `compute`

```dart
final data = await compute(callback, arguments);
```

Documentation:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/compute.html

Example:
[Flutter- compute method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52196555/flutter-compute-method)